# Trying to send MQTT message over websocket to SAP HCP platform(IoT) using node.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt, iot, sap-business-technology-platform

Here is my code.

```
// ========================================================================
// CONFIGURATION
// ========================================================================
var my_account_id='pxxxxxxxxxxtrial';
var my_device_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var my_oauth_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// ========================================================================

var endpoint = 'wss://iotmmspxxxxxxxxxxtrial.hanatrial.ondemand.com/com.sap.iotservices.mms/v1/api/ws/mqtt';

var options = {
keepalive: 60,
username: my_device_id,
password: my_oauth_token,
connectTimeout: 5 * 1000,
clientId: my_device_id,
protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
protocolVersion: 3,
clean: true,
will: null
};

console.log(options);

// ========================================================================

var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect(endpoint, options);

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected!');
  var data = {"mode":"async","messageType":"919762ab861ea779534a","messages":[{"Weight": 99,"timestamp":1413191650}]};
  client.publish('iot/data/'+my_device_id, JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});

client.on('error', function () {
  console.log('error!');
});

client.on('offline', function () {
  console.log('offline!');
});

client.on('close', function () {
  console.log('close!');
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString());
  //client.end();
});
```

Console.log output only shows "offline!" and "close!". It never shows "connected!". I've tried the answer on this page https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3955899 but still I can't make it work. What is going wrong in my code?